# get all occurence of substring between two chracters in java

Tags: java, string, substring

I have String Path like this

```
 "/Math/Math1/Algerbra/node"
```

how I can get all the occurence of substring between "/" and "/" to get (Math-Math1-Algerbra)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need the first 3 directories from a path. You can split on delimiter `"/"` and build from the result the new string. Obvious you have to pay attention if there aren't enough directories in the path.

```
    String s = "/Math/Math1/Algerbra/node";
    String aux[] = s.split("/");

    System.out.println(aux[1]+"-"+aux[2]+"-"+aux[3]);
```

Just found something better to join the strings (java 1.8):

```
    String.join("-", aux[1], aux[2], aux[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "a/b".split("/") to receive an array containing "a" and "b".

You have to pay some attention, as your first character is a separator, too. Also: do not assume that you know the size of the returned array; too often, people get something wrong and run into ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions because they dont't bother to check result.length before accessing the array elements.